# Creating Elasticsearch Index using NEST 5.x

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to create an index using NEST 5.x pre release version for Elasticsearch 5.x. I have samples from 2.x which shows how index can be created using ElasticClient.CreateIndex method. Below is my sample code.

```
ESnode = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
Nodesettings = new ConnectionSettings(ESnode);
Client = new ElasticClient(Nodesettings);
```

However, when I am typing below, there is NO autocomplete available.

```
Client.CreateIndex( c => c.
```

I am able to successfully get the health of the node using below code.

```
var res = Client.ClusterHealth();
Console.WriteLine("Status:" + res.Status);
```

I am having a complex document mapping for which I have defined the class structure and intend to use Automap method. Hence I am trying to create the index programatically to avoid manually creating the index.

I tried using some very old version of NEST (1.x) and I am able to get the autocomplete for createIndex. But both v2.4x and 5.x did not provide the autocomplete. Is there a new way to create index? Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to supply a name to the index, in addition to the delegate that provides additional index creation options

```
var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex("index-name", c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .NumberOfShards(1)
        .NumberOfReplicas(0)
    )
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Conference>(d => d
            .AutoMap()
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks Russ. I was about to delete the question as I figured it by trial. I was able to create the index. But I had a second question. When I used the Automap, even nested properties also got mapped as simple properties. Also, second issue that I noticed was that all the properties were sorted by property name (when I tried the GET mapping). How do I correct these?

Comment: CLR types will be mapped as `object` field mappings by default when using `.AutoMap()` (except those in NEST that are known e.g. `Attachment` type). In order to map as `nested` types, you need to override the automapping with `.Properties()`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/auto-map.html#auto-mapping-with-overrides. With regards to property names in json, they are never guaranteed to be in any particular order in json so order should not be relied upon.